# Unable to connect LAMP

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp, localhost

I have Ubuntu 18.04, Apache, MySQL and PHP7.4 in my local environment and I have been setting up various projects locally in both Laravel and WordPress. I haven't done this in over a year since I have started using docker so I am not sure if I am missing something obvious.
I am getting this error when attempting to navigate to my WordPress website I have set up locally.

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
myproject.development.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

The usual steps I do when creating a new project locally are similar to the DigitalOcean guide found here.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-18-04

Creating a DB and installing PHP Extensions. Enabling config files.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myproject.development
    ServerAlias www.myproject.development
    DocumentRoot /home/myname/projects/myproject
 
    <Directory "/home/darko/projects/tdd/">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
 
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Permissions

```
sudo find /home/myname/projects/myproject/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; 
sudo find /home/myname/projects/myproject/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; 
sudo chown -R myname:www-data /home/myname/projects/myproject/
```

Is there a way to check where is the error? I don't see anything in my logs

Comment: Have you confirmed that `myproject.development` is configured to point to `127.0.0.1` in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: yes, that is configured, I just realized I was attempting to reach https:// myproject.development instead of http:// myproject.development I spent all day checking if everything is setup correctly only for a friend to point me out the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I was attempting to reach https:// myproject.development instead of http:// myproject.development I spent all day checking if everything is setup correctly only for a friend to point me out the obvious